# Remove the '-' dividers in JSON keys in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, key-value

I'm trying to read some JSON data from the Tumblr API.

I'm using the Hashie gem to read the values as object properties. This should make reading easier/cleaner.

it turns something like this:

```
data['post']['title']
```

into this:

```
data.post.title
```

Unfortunately there are some keys showing up with a '-' as divider between like this:

```
regular-title: Mijn eerste post
format: html
regular-body: <p>post</p>
```

therefore i cannot use post.regular-title. Is there a way to replace all the minus(-) symbols into underscores(_)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it:

```
def convert_object(data)
  case data
    when Hash
      data.inject({}) do |h,(k,v)|
        h[(k.respond_to?(:tr) ? k.tr('-', '_') : k)] = convert_object(v)
        h
      end
    when Array
      data.map { |i| convert_object(i) }
    else
      data
  end
end
```

You can use it like this:

```
convert_object(JSON.parse('{"something-here":"value","otherkey":{"other-key":"value-value"}}'))
```

Comment: That looks better than my ugly coding :).

Answer (score 0):

Karaszi Istvan helped me a lot with the solution. I added the check for an array in the hash. This way hashes in arrays in the hash will get underscored too.

```
def convert_hash(hash)
  case hash
  when Hash
    hash.inject({}) do |h,(k,v)|
      h[k.tr('-', '_')] = convert_hash(v)
      h
    end
  when Array
    array = hash
    number = 0
    array.each do 
      array[number] = convert_hash(array[number])
      number += 1
    end
    array
  else
    hash
  end
end
```

I don't know why i added the 'number' as iterator. Somehow hash.each didn't work.